# Open Declaration won't work for some projects in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 to develop several jdk 1.8.0_74 Java projects.

The thing is - for one of these projects, things like Open Declaration to get to function declarations and such work fine for one project.  For another it doesn't work.  I'm not doing anything different or setting anything different that I know of.

I never had this problem with Kepler.  Open Declaration et al just always worked right out of the starting gate.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you also using maven?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Is that a plug-in?  What I don't quite get is that some projects in the workspace work fine - others don't.  If I were just missing a plug-in - I would think it would affect the entire workspace.

Comment: it's a build management tool. If your project use it you will have a po.xml file in the project folder